# Node.JS & Mongo.DB - Return contents of a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently writing a function where it finds all objects in a collection and returns them. I am having trouble getting the return to work. `console.log(result);` works, but the return just returns `undefined`. The database name is `projectDB` and collection is `projects`.

Here is the code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/projectDB";

function allObjects() {
  var projectResultDB;
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to DB!");
    var dbo = db.db("projectDB");

    dbo.collection("projects").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
      projectResultDB = result;
    });

  });
  return projectResultDB;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write allObjects() as a promise function like below and call with async/await

```
function allObjects() {
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected to DB!");
      var dbo = db.db("projectDB");

      dbo.collection("projects").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
        resolve(result)
      });
    });
  )};
}
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing this into a program? I haven't used async functions yet. Sorry for being such a pain!

Comment: from where you are calling this function?

Comment: `
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(allObjects());
});
`

Comment: allObejects().then(output=>{console.log(output)}); add this inside instead of console.log

Answer (score 0):

`dbo.collection` is asynchronouus do the following

```
dbo.collection("projects").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();      
      return result;
    });

  });
```

Comment: This still returns `undefined` for me. Weird.

Comment: @Slip Dip can you print `console.log(result)` and post what's its printing??

Comment: Inside function: ` [ { _id: 5d9f05e46bdc3f396bbcf907,
    name: 'testing.',
    type: 'staticWeb' },
  { _id: 5d9f07aa0cf7843ba79014b4,
    name: 'vchcgvh',
    type: 'staticWeb' },
  { _id: 5d9f07ccacb64f3e29183cc5,
    name: 'cvhfbgftdfgf',
    type: 'staticWeb' } ] ` Outside functions (`console.log(allObjects());`): `undefined`

Comment: Outside function you can't access because of its   `asynchronouus` nature, that's y I returned inside the db call.

Comment: I don't get this, I would have thought if I did `console.log(allObjects());` it would return it and print the database array to the console but it doesn't. I'm really sorry if i'm just being completely stupid.